# Unauthorized Access in Grails App with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

App Info:

- Grails Version: 3.1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_60
- Spring Security: spring-security-core:3.1.1

I have a School Controller. This contains various methods. The Admin user has access to this method.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def saveSchool(School newSchool) {
    def theSchool = schoolService.saveSchool(newSchool)

    if (theSchool) {
        render theSchool as JSON
    } else {
        render newSchool as JSON
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save the school using AJAX as if there are any error messages I want them to appear on the same form.

```
<g:javascript>

    $('#insertSchool').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<g:createLink controller="school" action="saveSchool"/>',
            data: $("#insertSchool").serialize(),
            success: function(theSchool) {
           '<g:createLink controller="school" view="saveSchool" model="theSchool"/>'
            }
        })

    });

</g:javascript>
```

The data is persisting to the database and I am being redirected to the saveSchool view however I'm getting a 403.

Comment: Why don't you separate incontroller function saving new school instance (and returning JSON) from the view function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why (or when) you are getting an error 403, but I think you need to reorganize your action and your view/js.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def save(School newSchool) {

    //First, validate the new school
    if(!newSchool.validate){
        ...
        //send a proper error code and send errors to the response
    }

    //save the school
    schoolService.saveSchool(newSchool)

    //render the school
    render newSchool as JSON
}
```

-

```
<g:javascript>

    $('#insertSchool').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '${g.createLink( controller:'school', action:'saveSchool')}',
            data: $("#insertSchool").serialize(),
            success: function(theSchool) {
                //You received the school as JSON, use JS to show it
                ...
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Handle errors
            }
        })

    });

</g:javascript>
```

I hope this helps you.